# Saving variables from execute() function in Operator Class

Tags: python, operator

I have this operator code which I call with `layout.operator("wm_filetype_source_operator")` function in my Panel class:

```
import bpy

class EasyImport_OT_File_Type_Op(bpy.types.Operator):

    bl_label = "File Type"
    bl_idname = "wm.filetype_source_operator"

    filetype_enum : bpy.props.EnumProperty(
        name = "",
        description = "Select an Source",
        items = [
            ('OP1', "FBX", "Set FBX as File Type"),
            ('OP2', "GLTF", "Set GLTF as File Type"),
            ('OP3', "BLEND", "Set BLEND as File Type"),
            ('OP4', "ABC", "Set ABC as File Type")
        ]
    )

    def invoke(self, context, event):
        wm = context.window_manager
        return wm.invoke_props_dialog(self)

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        layout.prop(self, "filetype_enum")
        

    def execute(self, context):

        global filetype
        if self.filetype_enum == 'OP1':
            filetype = 'FBX'
        elif self.filetype_enum == 'OP2':
            filetype = 'GLTF'
        elif self.filetype_enum == 'OP3':
            filetype = 'BLEND'
        elif self.filetype_enum == 'OP4':
            filetype = 'ABC'

        return {'FINISHED'}
```

The script works fine, but I cannot figure out how to save the `filetype` variable outside of the function.

So far I have tried the following:

- Set `filetype` variable to `global`
- Define the `filetype` variable outside the class and set it to `global`
- Return the `filetype` variable

None have worked and there doesn't seem to be any info on the doc about how to do this

Answer (score 1):

It's usually a bad idea to use `global` variables. I think it would be more straightforward to display your property in a panel. You can attach it to the current scene for instance.

```
import bpy


class HelloWorldPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_label = "Hello World Panel"
    bl_idname = "OBJECT_PT_hello"
    bl_space_type = 'PROPERTIES'
    bl_region_type = 'WINDOW'
    bl_context = "scene"

    def draw(self, context):
        self.layout.prop(context.scene, "my_filetype")
        


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(HelloWorldPanel)
    bpy.types.Scene.my_filetype= bpy.props.EnumProperty(
        name="Filetype", 
        items=(("FBX",) * 3, ("GTLF",) * 3,("BLEND",) * 3,("ABC",) * 3))



if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

That way you can access it directly with `bpy.context.scene.my_filetype`.

[image]

It creates a panel in the scene properties, but you can layout the prop anywhere in your custom UI. If you absolutely want to use an operator, you can just modify the `draw` method :

```
    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        layout.prop(context.scene, "my_filetype")
```

Answer (score -1):

Simple fix
You need to put the global variable inside of each if statement.

```
if self.filetype_enum == 'OP1':
    global filetype = 'FBX'
    filetype = 'FBX'
```

and then just repeat that for each elif statement.

Your welcome.